# Blender hide "safe - frames"

Tags: interface, 3d-view

how to hide these frames when looking from camera?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe Area marks for the frame can be toggled with the safe Area box on the camera settings

[image]

But in the image on the question there are no "safe" marks: the red outline appears when you lock your camera to view or when you use a render border. In the first case press <kbd>N</kbd> to access the View section and uncheck "Lock Camera to View".

[image]

If you are using a Render border you can clear it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

If the issue is that the camera view (the brighter rectangle) is too small on the screen, then press <kbd>Home</kbd> to have the camera view fill the window.

(This works even when the camera is in **locked to view** mode).

If the camera is not locked to view, using the mouse scroll wheel (Or <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and  <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>) will make the camera view larger (or smaller) on the screen.

[image]

The other lines on that gigantic motorcycle are likely lines of objects that are parented to each other.[image]